# Iphone Game Development

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm new to iPhone development, I bought the certificate a while back and have already posted one simple app on the app store(Lunch Money, just in case you are curious), but I've been looking all over the internet for a good series for iPhone openGL ES(2d or 3d will work) game development.

Does anyone know a good starting point for iphone opengl es game development?

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720901/learning-iphone-game-development , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148143/what-are-some-good-iphone-3d-2d-opengl-es-game-tutorials

Comment: What’s wrong with your previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148143?

Comment: i just can't find what i need...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[8 Great Resources For Learning Iphone OpenGL ES](http://maniacdev.com/2009/04/8-great-resources-for-learning-iphone-opengl-es/) & [16 Killer iPhone OpenGL ES Resources](http://maniacdev.com/2009/07/16-killer-opengl-es-resources/) contains a lot of information, even about games development.

**EDIT**: As per your comment, I add the following resources :

- [iPhone Game Development: Developing 2D & 3D games in Objective-C](http://www.amazon.co.uk/iPhone-Game-Development-Developing-Objective-C/dp/0596159854), a good start.
- [OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/OpenGL-ES-2-0-Programming-Guide/dp/0321502795/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1251699717&sr=1-6), the ultimate guide to learn ES.
- [iPhone OpenGL ES Tutorial Series](http://web.me.com/smaurice/AppleCoder/iPhone_OpenGL/Archive.html), great, contains specific information about games.

Comment: those are good... but i need something like ground up from objective-c basics to game programming

Comment: You're going to need more than one. Going from learning Objective C to OpenGL is not something that is well covered by one resource

Answer (score 1):

In the best 'cross platform' tradition, I wouldn't pin myself to objective-c that much.

Make the thinnest of GUI container in objective-c (touch handling, basic file io, etc) and make your game in C++ and opengl.

This way, you can potentially port your code to any other platform you might want to run it on and not box yourself in.